# IBM Worklight: Using native page in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ibm-mobilefirst

I have followed [this tutorial (06_02_iOS_-_Using_native_pages_in_hybrid_applications)](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/06_02_iOS_-_Using_native_pages_in_hybrid_applications.pdf) in order to display the native ViewController through Worklight API - `WL.NativePage.show`. And is able to go back to the hybrid page through `[NativePage showWebView:]`.

There are two screens in my application:

Screen A: Hybrid page (with a button to go to Screen B)

Screen B: Native page (in which there is a textbox to input some values and with a back button to go back to Screen A)

Here is my step:

1. Go to Screen B (native) from Screen A (hybrid)
2. Input some values in the native page
3. Click back button to go back to Screen A
4. Go to Screen B again from Screen A --> **In this step, the values which I previoulsy typed are still here.**

Is it possible to freshly go to Screen B everytime? Like in Android, I can use finish() on clicking the back button.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this should be solved in Objective-C code (meaning, not exactly related to Worklight), in the sense that you need to simply clear the text field right before you go back to the Hybrid page.

Comment: I would like to initialize the ViewController again. However, the call viewDidLoad is not being called in second time. Will there be any caching done in Worklight which has cached the content of ViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got this to work by setting `self.view = nil`.

```
// implement function when back button is pressed
- (IBAction)pressOnBackButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"pressOnBackButton");
    NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    [NativePage showWebView:dic];

    self.view = nil;
}
```